# Django docker-compose after restart requires migration again

Tags: python, django, docker, docker-compose, cookiecutter-django

I made this unit file.

```
[Unit]
Description=myservice
Requires=docker.service
After=docker.service

[Service]
Restart=always

# Remove old containers, images and volumes
ExecStartPre=/usr/local/bin/docker-compose -f my.yml down -v
ExecStartPre=/usr/local/bin/docker-compose -f my.yml rm -v
ExecStartPre=-/bin/bash -c 'docker volume rm $(docker volume ls -q)'
ExecStartPre=-/bin/bash -c 'docker rmi $(docker images | grep "<none>" | awk \'{print $3}\')'
ExecStartPre=-/bin/bash -c 'docker rm -v $(docker ps -aq)'

# Compose up
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/docker-compose -f my.yml up

# Compose down, remove containers and volumes
ExecStop=/usr/local/bin/docker-compose -f my.yml down -v

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Before running this file, I create the migration like this:

```
docker-compose -f my.yml run --rm django python manage.py migrate
```

But, after rebooting the OS, I need to restart the migration, because they are not detected.
What can be wrong?

Comment: You do not mention where you keep your database, but those commands in the posted service file will remove all docker containers (`docker rm -v $(docker ps -aq)`) and all docker volumes currently on your machine (`docker volume rm $(docker volume ls -q)`).  if your database is created within a started container or otherwise on an associated volume (and not in an actual image), it looks like you are clearing everything out each time you start or stop the service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the experiments, I made here such a unit file, which works as it should.

```
[Unit]
Description=myservice
Requires=docker.service
After=docker.service

[Service]
Restart=always

# Compose down
ExecStartPre=/usr/local/bin/docker-compose -f my.yml down

# Compose up
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/docker-compose -f my.yml up

# Compose down
ExecStop=/usr/local/bin/docker-compose -f my.yml down

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```